# What port does Netflix device streaming use?

Tags: video-streaming, netflix, traffic-filtering, transparentproxy

What port does Netflix device streaming use?

Is this port also used by the website direct streaming in the Silverlight app? What is the HTTP Content-Type if it uses port 80? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Playback session(s) on devices are almost identical for browser-based sessions. The service uses HTTP and HTTPS session protocols (SSL-443) to netflix's CDN (https://moviecontrol.netflix.com)

Take a look at Pomelollc's blog [here](https://pomelollc.wordpress.com/2009/04/15/on-netflixs-video-streaming-security-framework) for a more detailed explanation of Netflix's video streaming security framework.

Comment: I am curious about how this could interfere with a content-filtering transparent proxy. Specifically what is the content-type via HTTP? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry my friend, transparent proxies can be detected. And many of the streaming services block the use of them. See here: http://www.changeiponline.com/tag/transparent-proxy/

Comment: A transparent proxy of the kind I am using cannot be detected because no modification or redirection of packets is done, only filtering (like a firewall). I was just wondering what Content-Type Netflix uses so I don't filter on that.

Comment: According to http://developer.netflix.com/docs/REST_API_Conventions The Content-Type is x-application/x-gzip